# Angular: How to handle null value in angular material table

Tags: angular, error-handling, undefined

I wanted to apply css class based on the status. Eg: if status is `Pass`, css class `.dot .pass` should be assigned to `span` in html. How I can handle the `null` value if api return `status: null`. I'm getting this error message `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined`. I belived this was caused by null value in status.

**status.constant.ts**

```
export const STATUSES_KEY = {
  notChecked: 'NOT_CHECKED',
  pass: 'PASS',
  na: 'NA',
  fail: 'FAIL'
};

export const STATUS_STYLING = {
  [STATUSES_KEY.notChecked]: {
    text: 'Not Checked',
    css: 'dot notChecked',
  },
  [STATUSES_KEY.pass]: {
    text: 'Pass',
    css: 'dot pass',
  },
  [STATUSES_KEY.fail]: {
    text: 'Fail',
    css: 'dot fail',
  }
};
```

**app.ts**

```
  generateStatusClass(status: string) {
    if (status) {
      return STATUS_STYLING[status].css;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
```

**app.html**

```
<span *ngIf="col === 'status'" class="{{ generateStatusClass(element[col]) }}"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `generateStatusClass(status: string)` method you are checking if `status` is truthy, but not if there is a value for the status in your dictionary (for example `na` is not present). Change the code to something like this;

```
 generateStatusClass(status: string) {
    if (status && STATUS_STYLING[status]) {
      return STATUS_STYLING[status].css;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
```

Also, I am not sure if `class={{...}}` works. You might want to change this to `ngClass`, like this;

```
<span *ngIf="col === 'status'" [ngClass]="generateStatusClass(element[col])"></span>
```

Comment: error has gone now but css class not applying in span class. Eventhough I used `[ngClass]`

Comment: @Johnny - you might want to `console.log(status)` in your method to see that you're getting the expected value from element[col].

Comment: Yes, it is returning correct value but not reflecting in class

Comment: Do you see the class applied when inspecting the element? The css class might be out of scope if you're sure the correct string really gets returned from your method.

Comment: Yes it is. But when inspect the element, it doesn't reflect. Weird

Comment: Then it sounds like the css classes you return cannot be found. Add a static <span class="dot pass">SomeText</span> and investigate from there.. If you're using component styles, move the classes to `src/styles.css`, etc.